# Pattern for form input field validation

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have following scenario, I have to validate the form input field whose first character can be either P or B or R, the second character can only be C and after that 6 digits. I was using this pattern:

```
pattern="^[PBR]C\d{6,6}$"
```

Now I have to add one more condition to the input field to allow input of the form BRC100101, so now the input can also start from BR, then letter C and then 6 digits. I tried the below pattern, but couldn't quite get what I'm looking for.

```
pattern="^(P)(B)(R)(BR)C\d{6,6}$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Least amount of characters and more professional.

```
([PBR]|BR)C\d{6}
```

This way is little easier to read/understand, readability goes a long way.

```
(P|B|R|BR)C\d{6}
```

I'm not a regular expresssion expert, I usually use regexr.com to help me build and test the expressions I use in my code.

http://regexr.com/

Demo:
http://regexr.com/3ggi6

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

```
([PBR]|BR)C\d{6,6}
```

Live Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RN86w1/2

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
([PBR]|BR)C\d{6}
```

Demo https://regex101.com/r/SDgguC/1